# FormCollection is not getting passed to the controller

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms

I can post elements from my form if I make a direct reference to the named element in the controller parameters.  I am trying to use FormCollection so I do not have to type every element from the form in the post ActionResult parameters.

**The HTML form:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("legallabels", "Reports", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "reportForm", @class = "report-form col-9" }))
{
    <div class="col-12">
        <b>Beginning </b><input type="text" class="form-control col-2" id="beginningDatePicker" name="beginningDate" value="@DateTime.Today.Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")" />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
}
```

**Controller using named parameter (beginningDate):**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LegalLabels(string beginningDate)
{
    return View();
}
```

**When using FormCollection, it does not get passed to the controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LegalLabels(FormCollection form)
{
    return View();
}
```

Using a breakpoint in the controller, I can see that the form is posting correctly and everything works fine when naming form elements (beginningDate) in the parameters.  I've looked at similar samples of code that use FormCollection and they seem to work fine.  Why are my FormCollection values not getting passed to the controller?

Comment: Btw, the way you're defining your textbox is not the preferred way in MVC. You create a model and use the razor helpers to generate the underlying html and attributes.

Answer (score 2):

Tested your code, it works fine. If you see the snippet below you can loop through all posted values and check.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LegalLabels(FormCollection form)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (var key in form.AllKeys)
    {
        sb.AppendLine(string.Format("Key: {0}. Value: {1}.<br>", key, form[key]));
    }

    ViewBag.FormData = sb.ToString();

    return View();
}
```

On the cshtml

```
<div>
    @Html.Raw(ViewBag.FormData)
</div>
```

Comment: I put a breakpoint on sb when it first gets initialized, and it never even triggered.  I'm pretty confused at this point..

Comment: I changed back from FormCollection to my named element "beginningDate" and my breakpoint stops where it never did before. It's like FormCollection isn't a recognized element in MVC or something..

Comment: I tested this in MVC, (not core). So it definitely works. Maybe try it in a 'clean' project to eliminate all other possible interference.

Comment: I just read through a large error log and found that I needed to rename my FormCollection to IFormCollection. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

After renaming FormCollection to IFormCollection, everything is working properly.

Comment: Could you mention the namespace for the IFormCollection class? I don't think it's present in the default web using System.Web.Mvc module.

Answer (score 0):

Install from NuGet **Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core**

this will install the following:
**Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client** & **Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core**

Once these are installed, clean and rebuild your solution.
Then your Put or Post request from an ajax call will parse your form elements into a FormCollection to your controller.